# How to get the maximum value between specific index of pandas column?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, max

I have a dataframe which has date index and pool of positive and negative values

```
values = [1,2,3,4,-1,-2,-3,10,11,12]
start_date = pd.to_datetime('2019-01-23')
dates = [start_date + datetime.timedelta(days=i) for i in range(0,len(values))]
df = pd.DataFrame(values)
df.columns = ['values'] ; df.index = dates ; df
```

I want to have an additional column which will have the maximum value of 1st group of positive values and the minimum value of 2nd group of negative values and so on.

The output should look like

```
df['values_max'] = np.nan
df.loc['2019-01-26','values_max'] = 4
df.loc['2019-01-29','values_max'] = -3
df.loc['2019-02-01','values_max'] = 12
df
```

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use:

```
#map positive and negative values to 1, -1
s = np.sign(df['values'])
#create consecutive groups
g = s.ne(s.shift()).cumsum()
#create new columns with consition
df['new'] = df.groupby(g)['values'].transform(lambda x: x.max() if x.max() > 0 else x.min())
#add missing values
df.loc[df['new'] != df['values'], 'new'] = np.nan
print (df)
            values   new
2019-01-23       1   NaN
2019-01-24       2   NaN
2019-01-25       3   NaN
2019-01-26       4   4.0
2019-01-27      -1   NaN
2019-01-28      -2   NaN
2019-01-29      -3  -3.0
2019-01-30      10   NaN
2019-01-31      11   NaN
2019-02-01      12  12.0
```